# Install python module by first creating the wheel

Tags: python, setup.py

I just download files to build an API in python - a brief tuto on that API suggest that in order to install it a module, the following must be performed:

```
* you can use this to build a wheel

python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

* you can use this to install the wheel

python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade dist/ibapi-9.73.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

This seems pretty straightforward, however I am completely unfamilar with that aspect of python and a bit at loss... I tried to run the command `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` both in the folder containing the API and by first entering a python 3 environement (by typing `source activate python3` - i am using anaconda. Both return the error `setup.py cannot be found`.

Anyone knows where both command should be run in order to properly install the module?

Comment: Were you able to build the wheel file? I am trying to do the same thing but I got a return message saying bdist_wheel doesn't exist as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write setup script for your module

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below:

1. `cd  C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient`
2. `python setup.py bdist_wheel`
3. `cd C:\Python36\Scripts`
4. `python -m pip install --upgrade "C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\dist\ibapi-9.73.2-py3-none-any.whl"`

Note: Change python and API versions to the ones you are using.